# Is a landlord required to give 24 hours notice of entry again if they previously did so but cancelled?

Tags: tenant, lease, notice

Our landlord has typically been good about emailing us at least a day in advance as they've been showing our leased house almost 3 times a week for the past month. However, they recently sent an email saying they would be holding a showing today but later followed up and said that it had been cancelled and that no one would be coming. Then, with 30 minutes of notice, they notified us that the showing would be happening after all and let themselves in with almost 15 people attending.

Normally I wouldn't take issue with this for the sake of common decency, but our landlord has a bad habit of allowing prospective tenants to walk through the rooms (specifically my attached unit) unsupervised. Given that I have some very expensive computing equipment that I'm contractually obligated through work to keep secure (as well as not wanting people walking off with my own stuff), I ensure that I'm home during the showings.

I don't think any of us intend to take legal action, but it would be nice to know whether the law around reasonable notice protects us in this case as we discuss things with our landlord to prevent this from occurring in the future.

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: Sorry- this is in California